# Yang: negative lookahead equivalent?

Tags: java, regex

I wrote the following regular expression

```
(?!.[$][(]).*.
```

This regular expression is used to reject any string containing `$(` (if the string contains `$` or `(`, the string will be valid ). Anyway, this solution is working using java, but I need another solution without using `?!` (negative lookahead ) that works with yang.

This link shows how to user regular expression with Yang https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/#regexs

Comment: That is not a negative lookbehind but a negative _lookahead_ you are using here. A negative lookbehind is `(?<!...)`.

Comment: Java regex for a string not containing `$(` is `(?s)^(?!.*[$][(]).*$`. Why don't you want a negative lookahead?

Comment: `?!` is not negative lookbehind; it is negative _lookahead_. Why exactly do you need to avoid a negative lookahead?

Comment: Also, there are two simple ways to do it without a lookahead: first, invert the logic and use a regex to try and find `[$(]`; if no match you are good. Another solution is to check that both `.indexOf('$')` and `.indexOf('(')` are -1.

Comment: If the string must not contain `$(` then why don't you just use `boolean invalid = string.matches(".*\\$\\s*\\(.*");`?

Comment: @Thomas Or even better (faster): `boolean valid = (string.indexOf("$(") == -1);`

Comment: @Andreas that supposes that `$` and `(` are attached; it's unclear from the OP whether that is the case. Otherwise, yes, that is certainly the faster (and better) solution

Comment: @Andreas yes, depends on whether whitespace is allowed in between or not.

Comment: @fge `(`, not `{`. Oops. Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: @Thomas Both the regex in question and the question text has `$(` with no space allowed.

Comment: I forgot the dot-all flag in my expression which then would become `(?s).*\$\s*\(.*`

Comment: @Andreas yes it implies that whitespace is not allowed (or the OP simply didn't think about that). It all depends on what this is used for (it might be better to match even with whitespace in between to be safe, e.g. when this is some kind of security validation) - if whitespace is definitely not allowed then your suggestion is the better one (faster, easier to read and understand).

Comment: Thanks everybody. I need it without ?! negative lookahead beacuse it's not supported in my language (ncs). I should write pattern in Yang file, and when I added this pattern it causes an exception.

Comment: @DaoudShaheen if it's not for Java then why did you set that tag?

Comment: Sorry for that. It's by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex

```
([^$]|[$]+[^($])*[$]*
```

This matches `$`s only if it's followed by the end of the string or something other than `(`.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working with java, but not with Yang it gives me bad pattern exception. This link will help you how to use regular expression with Yang https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/#regexs

Comment: @DaoudShaheen: Edited the answer. Does the new version work?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working but if I want to add a new character to the filter for example 'a' so I want to filter by $( or a , how can I do it. I try to add (([^$]|[$]+[^($])([^a]))*$ but it did not work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: If `a` must not occur in the string, you need to remove it from every character group where it could occur, i.e. from **every** negative character group in this case: `([^a$]|[$]+[^a($])*[$]*`

Answer (score 0):

My approach looks a bit complicated:

```
^([^$]+?|[^(]+?|.*?(?:\$[^(][^\$]*?))$
```

[REGEX 101 DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/uQ1dD3/1)